# How did 16-bit C compilers work?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, legacy, 16-bit

C's memory model, with its use of pointer arithmetic and all, seems to model flat address space.  16-bit computers used segmented memory access.  How did 16-bit C compilers deal with this issue and simulate a flat address space from the perspective of the C programmer?  For example, roughly what assembly language instructions would the following code compile to on an 8086?

```
long arr[65536];  // Assume 32 bit longs.
long i;
for(i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: To be fair, a purely 16-bit system would have a flat model, and few processors outside x86 ever used segmentation.

Comment: Assuming `int` is 16-bit, your for loop invokes undefined behavior (due to integer overflow) and will likely result in an infinite loop (since `i<65536` will always evaulate to true..but after UB is invoked, *anything* could happen).

Comment: The past tense of *did* is a bit rough — there are plenty of 16-bit architectures still in widespread use, with corresponding C compilers.

Comment: C does not specify a flat memory model. Pointer arithmetic with pointers that point to different "objects" is undefined, because they could be pointing to different segments. Before paging won, I'm pretty sure there were some architectures where pointers were (segment,offset) at the hardware level, where segment was an index into a (more-than-size-4) segment table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How did 16-bit C compilers deal with
>   this issue and simulate a flat address
>   space from the perspective of the C
>   programmer?

They didn't.  Instead, they made segmentation visible to the C programmer,  extending the language by having multiple types of pointers: [`near`, `far`, and `huge`](http://web.archive.org/web/20100824061543/http://www.utdallas.edu/~rxc064000/cracktheinterview/pages/6_16.html).  A `near` pointer was an offset only, while `far` and `huge` pointers were a combined segment and offset.  There was a compiler option to set the [memory model](http://www.sis.pitt.edu/~ir/KS/Data/PBurden/chap6.msdos.memory.html), which determined whether the default pointer type was near or far.

In Windows code, even today, you'll often see typedefs like `LPCSTR` (for `const char*`).  The "LP" is a holdover from the 16-bit days; it stands for "Long (far) Pointer".

Comment: Except, as the other answer said, pure 16-bit compilers worked just as it works nowadays. For instance, the Turbo C compiler in "small" and "tiny" mode used only 16-bit pointers. .COM files in DOS use pure 16 bit pointers.

Answer (score 10):

The true 16-bit environments use 16 bit pointers which reach any address.  Examples include the PDP-11, 6800 family (6802, 6809, 68HC11), and the 8085.  This is a clean and efficient environment, just like a simple 32-bit architecture.

The 80x86 family forced upon us a hybrid 16-bit/20-bit address space in so-called "real mode"—the native 8086 addressing space.  The usual mechanism to deal with this was enhancing the types of pointers into two basic types, `near` (16-bit pointer) and `far` (32-bit pointer).  The default for code and data pointers can be set in bulk by a "memory model":  `tiny`, `small`, `compact`, `medium`, `far`, and `huge` (some compilers do not support all models).

The `tiny` memory model is useful for small programs in which the entire space (code + data + stack) is less than 64K.  All pointers are (by default) 16 bits or `near`; a pointer is implicitly associated with a segment value for the whole program.

The `small` model assumes that data + stack is less than 64K and in the same segment; the code segment contains only code, so can have up to 64K as well, for a maximum memory footprint of 128K.  Code pointers are `near` and implicitly associated with CS (the code segment).  Data pointers are also `near` and associated with DS (the data segment).

The `medium` model has up to 64K of data + stack (like small), but can have any amount of code.  Data pointers are 16 bits and are implicitly tied to the data segment.  Code pointers are 32 bit `far` pointers and have a segment value depending on how the linker has set up the code groups (a yucky bookkeeping hassle).

The `compact` model is the complement of medium:  less than 64K of code, but any amount of data.  Data pointers are `far` and code pointers are `near`.

In `large` or `huge` model, the default subtype of pointers are 32 bit or `far`.  The main difference is that huge pointers are always automatically normalized so that incrementing them avoids problems with 64K wrap arounds.   See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model).

Comment: You have conflated memory models (tiny, small, compact, medium, huge) with pointer types (far, huge).

Comment: Simply because one depends on the other does not mean that they are the same thing.  For example, there is no such thing as a `tiny` pointer - pointers were `near`, `far` or `huge`.  Rather, `tiny` was a memory model.  Memory models were defined by what type of pointers code and data were by default, and what segment was used for `near` pointers.  In the case of `tiny`, both code and data used `near` pointers, and both types of `near` pointers referenced the same segment.

Answer (score 10):

C memory model does not in any way imply flat address space. It never did. In fact, C language specification is specifically designed to allow non-flat address spaces.

In the most trivial implementation with segmented address space, the size of the largest continuous object would be limited by the size of the segment (65536 bytes on a 16 bit platform). This means that `size_t` in such implementation would be 16 bit, and that your code simply would not compile, since you are attempting to declare an object that has larger size than the allowed maximum.

A more complex implementation would support so called *huge* memory model. You see, there's really no problem addressing continuous memory blocks of *any* size on a segmented memory model, it just requires some extra efforts in pointer arithmetics. So, within the huge memory model, the implementation would make those extra efforts, which would make the code a bit slower, but at the same time would allow addressing objects of virtually any size. So, your code would compile perfectly fine.

Answer (score 7):

In DOS 16 bit, I dont remember being able to do that.  You could have multiple things that were each 64K (bytes)(because the segment could be adjusted and the offset zeroed) but dont remember if you could cross the boundary with a single array.  The flat memory space where you could willy nilly allocate whatever you wanted and reach as deep as you liked into an array didnt happen until we could compile 32 bit DOS programs (on 386 or 486 processors).  Perhaps other operating systems and compilers other than microsoft and borland could generate flat arrays greater than 64kbytes.  Win16 I dont remember that freedom until win32 hit, perhaps my memory is getting rusty...You were lucky or rich to have a megabyte of memory anyway, a 256kbyte or 512kbyte machine was not unheard of.  Your floppy drive had a fraction of a meg to 1.44 meg eventually, and your hard disk if any had a dozen or few meg, so you just didnt compute thing that large that often.

I remember the particular challenge I had learning about DNS when you could download the entire DNS database of all registered domain names on the planet, in fact you had to to put up your own dns server which was almost required at the time to have a web site.  That file was 35megabytes, and my hard disk was 100megabytes, plus dos and windows chewing up some of that.  Probably had 1 or 2 meg of memory, might have been able to do 32 bit dos programs at the time.  Part if it was me wanting to parse the ascii file which I did in multiple passes, but each pass the output had to go to another file, and I had to delete the prior file to have room on the disk for the next file. Two disk controllers on a standard motherboard, one for the hard disk and one for the cdrom drive, here again this stuff wasnt cheap, there were not a lot of spare isa slots if you could afford another hard disk and disk controller card.

There was even the problem of reading 64kbytes with C you passed fread the number of bytes you wanted to read in a 16 bit int, which meant 0 to 65535 not 65536 bytes, and performance dropped dramatically if you didnt read in even sized sectors so you just read 32kbytes at a time to maximize performance, 64k didnt come until well into the dos32 days when you were finally convinced that the value passed to fread was now a 32 bit number and the compiler wasnt going to chop off the upper 16 bits and only use the lower 16 bits (which happened often if you used enough compilers/versions).  We are currently suffering similar problems in the 32 bit to 64 transition as we did with the 16 to 32 bit transition. What is most interesting is the code from the folks like me that learned that going from 16 to 32 bit int changed size, but unsigned char and unsigned long did not, so you adapted and rarely used int so that your programs would compile and work for both 16 and 32 bit.  (The code from folks from that generation kind of stands out to other folks that also lived through it and used the same trick).  But for the 32 to 64 transition it is the other way around and code not refactored to use uint32 type declarations are suffering.

Reading wallyk's answer that just came in, the huge pointer thing that wrapped around does ring a bell, also not always being able to compile for huge.  small was the flat memory model we are comfortable with today, and as with today was easy because you didnt have to worry about segments.  So it was a desireable to compile for small when you could.  You still didnt have a lot of memory or disk or floppy space so you just didnt normally deal with data that large.

And agreeing with another answer, the segment offset thing was 8088/8086 intel.  The whole world was not yet dominated by intel, so there were other platforms that just had a flat memory space, or used other tricks perhaps in hardware (outside the processor) to solve the problem.  Because of the segment/offset intel was able to ride the 16 bit thing longer than it probably should have.  Segment/offset had some cool and interesting things you could do with it, but it was as much a pain as anything else.  You either simplified your life and lived in a flat memory space or you constantly worried about segment boundaries.

Answer (score 4):

Really pinning down the address size on old x86's is sort of tricky.  You could say that its 16 bit, because the arithmetic you can perform on an address must fit in a 16 bit register.  You could also say that it's 32 bit, because actual addresses are computed against a 16 bit general purpose register and 16 bit segment register (all 32 bits are significant).  You could also just say it's 20 bit, because the segment registers are shifted 4 bits left and added to the gp registers for hardware addressing.

It actually doesn't matter that much which one of these you chose, because they are all roughly equal approximations of the c abstract machine.  Some compilers let you pick a memory model you were using per compilation, while others just assume 32 bit addresses and then carefully check that operations that could overflow 16 bits emit instructions that handle that case correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer) wikipedia entry. About Far pointers. Basically, its possible to indicate a segment and an offset, making it possible to jump to another segment.